# How to connect Ruby on Rails to MySQL using ruby-mysql

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I get this error:

```
No connection pool with 'primary' found.
        raise ConnectionNotEstablished, "No connection pool with '#{spec_name}' found for the '#{ActiveRecord::Base.current_role}' role."
          else
            raise ConnectionNotEstablished, "No connection pool with '#{spec_name}' found."
          end
        end
```

This is my default:

```
&default
  adapter: ruby-mysql
  encoding: utf8mb4
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: 
  host: localhost
development:
  <<: *default
  database: demo_project_development
production:
  <<: *default
  database: demo_project_production
  username: root
  password: 
)
```

MySQL is runnning, the tutorial I was following was using the mysql2 adapter.

My Ruby version is 2.6.5.

Note I have no tables in my database:

```
activerecord (6.0.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:1117:in `retrieve_connection'
activerecord (6.0.1) lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:238:in `retrieve_connection'
activerecord (6.0.1) lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:206:in `connection'
activerecord (6.0.1) lib/active_record/migration.rb:562:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `block in call'
activesupport (6.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:101:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (6.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:26:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/actionable_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:32:in `call'
web-console (4.0.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:132:in `call_app'
web-console (4.0.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
web-console (4.0.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:17:in `catch'
web-console (4.0.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:33:in `call'
railties (6.0.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (6.0.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `block in call'
activesupport (6.0.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:80:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (6.0.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:28:in `tagged'
activesupport (6.0.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:80:in `tagged'
railties (6.0.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call'
sprockets-rails (3.2.1) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:81:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:27:in `call'
rack (2.0.7) lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
rack (2.0.7) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
activesupport (6.0.1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:29:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:126:in `call'
rack (2.0.7) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/host_authorization.rb:83:in `call'
webpacker (4.2.0) lib/webpacker/dev_server_proxy.rb:23:in `perform_request'
rack-proxy (0.6.5) lib/rack/proxy.rb:57:in `call'
railties (6.0.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:526:in `call'
puma (4.3.0) lib/puma/configuration.rb:228:in `call'
puma (4.3.0) lib/puma/server.rb:667:in `handle_request'
puma (4.3.0) lib/puma/server.rb:470:in `process_client'
puma (4.3.0) lib/puma/server.rb:328:in `block in run'
puma (4.3.0) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:134:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

Comment: Where and how do you get that error? It's not a stack trace. Show an **actual** error in the form of a stack trace. [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) please.

Comment: Don't say "getting an error" in the title, please try and focus on what the problem is, explain better what the error is.

Comment: @ cannot load such file -- mysql2/2.6/mysql2

Comment: [MRE] [MRE] [MRE]! **How** do you generate this error, what are your **steps to reproduce**, what is the **full example to allow this to be reproduced**?

Comment: running rails s command

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38176304/no-connection-pool-for-activerecordbase

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the `ruby-mysql` gem. Just by looking at the [github repo](https://github.com/tmtm/ruby-mysql) you can see that the last commit was four years ago and almost all the commits are from a single author, additionally the readme is in Japanese. That does not bode well.

Instead use the [mysql2 gem](https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2) which is actively maintained. You can generate a Rails application already set up for MySQL by running:

```
rails new my_app --database=mysql
```

Or, if you want to fix your existing application, replace `ruby-mysql` with `mysql2` in your Gemfile and set the correct adapter:

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  # ...
```

Comment: I did Now I need to install my sql2 so I get Error installing mysql2:
        mysql2 requires Ruby version < 2.6, >= 2.0.

Comment: Yeah, but why do you have a ruby version older than 2.0 in the first place? Thats really old

Comment: I have 2.6.5 @Max

Comment: What version of the mysql2 gem are you trying to install? 0.5.2 just lists the version as `s.required_ruby_version = '>= 2.0.0'`. You should be using something like `gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.5.2'`. https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2/blob/3b9a26708fa86aba23763626331eb317ed457cc1/mysql2.gemspec

Comment: so any soultion ?

Comment: Use the correct version in you gemfile - run bundle install.

Comment: I did still not working

Comment: "I did still not working" tells us nothing useful.

Comment: I did run bundle install